# Shift screen with xrandr

Tags: screen, display-resolution, xrandr

Some days ago I crashed my laptop's screen. For now I can only see a part (more than half screen) the right part, so the launcher and many things that appear usually at left are hidden, and most of the software I use has also its project browser at left (with no chance to change it).

So I want to know how can I shift the screen so I can see the entire system screen, no matter if I need to change resolution.

**Things I tried**

- `xrandr --output eDP1 --fb 1280x720`: Works, but the top left corner is still where it should be.
- `xrandr --output eDP1 --transform 1,0,-400,0,1,0,0,0,1` or `xrandr --output eDP1 --fb 966x768 --transform ...`: Also works but the indicators are not shown.
- `xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1024x768`: Works too (I don't care about black "borders" at left and right), but launch bar still not visible.
- `xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1024x768 --transform 1,0,-400,0,1,0,0,0,1`: Small screen but no indicators, just like the 2nd case.